# Java - downcast in clone

Tags: java, inheritance, clone, downcast

Lets say that `Class B` extends `class A` and `class A` is Cloneable as follows:

```
public class A implements Cloneable {
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        A ac = (A) super.clone();
        return ac;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B a = (B) super.clone();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Why it is legal to perform down-cast from A to B in the next line:

```
B a = (B) super.clone(); // (super of B is A)
```

while the next down-cast is run-time error?

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B) a.clone();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `B b = new B();` and `A a = (A) b.clone();` by any chance?

Comment: Excellent question about clone(), it was a thing that I couldn't wrap my head around, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ultimately, this is using [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) to create the object - and that's guaranteed to create a new object of the same execution-time type as the object it's called on:

> The method `clone` for class `Object` performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown. Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface `Cloneable` and that the return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]` where T is any reference or primitive type. Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

So if we get a call to `clone()` being executed on an instance of `B`, then `super.clone()` will return a `B` (or a subclass) - so the cast is valid.

In your second case, you're creating an instance of just `A`, which is *not* an instance of `B`, so the cast fails.

Comment: That's the reason why a clone method implementation should NEVER directly create the copy via new but should ALWAYS use super.clone() instead! Otherwise it is impossible to correctly override clone in subclasses!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer...When I debugged the code, the next code line:
      B a = (B) super.clone();
sent me to A.clone() which returns instance of A..so i don't understand how super.clone() return a B?

Comment: @HeshamYassin: No, `A.clone()` returns a reference which is *at least* an `A` - that's what's guaranteed by the cast to `A`. But it will *actually* be a `B` (or a subclass), because you're cloning an instance of `B`. Look at the value of `ac` in the debugger, and you'll see it's a reference to an instance of `B`.